# Multiple functions in jquery .live

Tags: jquery

I am wondering if it is possible to bind multiple function to one live event.

```
$('.block a.submit').live("click",
    function(){
        $(this).text('Save').parent().each(function(){
            $(".value", this).hide();
            $(".edit", this).show();
            $(this).find('.edit :first').focus(); //focuses on first form element - less clicks
            $('thead').show();
        });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).text('Edit').parent().each(function(){
            $(".edit", this).hide();
            $(".value", this).show();
            $('thead').hide();
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: if the live event was not `click` but was `hover` this would be valid

Comment: @Neal, no it would not. The `.live()` method accepts a single method to bind to the event. For the `hover` event it would just bind the single method provided to both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 2):

im not sure what you want to do, but yes you can, just split it in two:

```
$('.block a.submit').live("click",
    function(){
        $(this).text('Save').parent().each(function(){
            $(".value", this).hide();
            $(".edit", this).show();
            $(this).find('.edit :first').focus(); //focuses on first form element - less clicks
            $('thead').show();
        });
    }).live('click',
    function(){
        $(this).text('Edit').parent().each(function(){
            $(".edit", this).hide();
            $(".value", this).show();
            $('thead').hide();
        });
    }
);
```

or you can put both things you want to do in one function:

```
$('.block a.submit').live("click",
    function(){
        $(this).text('Save').parent().each(function(){
            $(".value", this).hide();
            $(".edit", this).show();
            $(this).find('.edit :first').focus(); //focuses on first form element - less clicks
            $('thead').show();
        });
        //second thing
        $(this).text('Edit').parent().each(function(){
            $(".edit", this).hide();
            $(".value", this).show();
            $('thead').hide();
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but you can merge your methods in one

```
$('.block a.submit').live("click",
    function(){
        $(this).text('Save').parent().each(function(){
            $(".value", this).hide();
            $(".edit", this).show();
            $(this).find('.edit :first').focus(); //focuses on first form element - less clicks
            $('thead').show();
        });

        $(this).text('Edit').parent().each(function(){
            $(".edit", this).hide();
            $(".value", this).show();
            $('thead').hide();
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.block a.submit').live("click","keydown","keyup",
       function(){
```

I believe like that.

Comment: This is wrong syntax (*should be `.live('click keydown keyup')`*), but the concept you talk is about binding one method to multiple events. The OP is asking multiple methods to one event.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the second `function() {`

Why would you want to limit the number of instructions in one anonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but I don't think you need to have live events here

Live events are only needed if you inject elements in the dom and want your existing
events to automatically hook themselves to the new elements..

In any case both bind and live will work with multiple listeners.

```
$('.block a.submit').bind("click",
      function(){
          $(this).text('Save').parent().each(function(){
              $(".value", this).hide();
              $(".edit", this).show();
              $(this).find('.edit :first').focus(); //focuses on first form element - less clicks
              $('thead').show();
          });
      }).bind("click",
      function(){
          $(this).text('Edit').parent().each(function(){
              $(".edit", this).hide();
              $(".value", this).show();
              $('thead').hide();
          });
      }
);
```